# I'm having some trouble with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, queue

My goal is to update a variable in my GUI when a button(from the GPIO on the raspberry pi) is pressed.
So I figured I would use multithreading.

When I start the application, only one of the threads executes. My main app (the GUI) does not launch.

I have been stuck with this problem for days, and it's driving me crazy! Thanks for taking the time to look at this.(there are probably multiple problems, sorry for that)

Here is my code:

```
snelheidsvar = 0
q = queue.Queue()

class worker():

    def run(self):
        global snelheidsvar #this is the variable that is passed around
        global q

        try: 
           .....
           #this checks what button is pressed   

           elif j == 0 and i == 3: # one of the buttons                                   
           snelheidsvar +=1
           print("snelheidsvar is:", snelheidsvar)
           q.put(snelheidsvar) #putting the variable in a queue
           time.sleep(0.5)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()
class SampleApp(tk.Tk, threading.Thread):
    .....
    #this arranges what frame is shown and builds them

class some_class(tk.Frame,threading.Thread): #this is also a frame
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

         .....
         self.some_label= tk.Label(some_frame, textvariable=self.local_variable) 
         #this is the variable that needs to be updated
         .....
         #putting in some more buttons and stuff

    def run(self):
         global snelheidsvar
         global q   

         q.get(snelheidsvar)
         self.local_variable = tk.IntVar()
         self.local_variable.set(snelheidsvar) 
         #taking it out of the queue and setting it to the local variable
if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = some_class(None, None) #not sure this should be None, None
    b = worker()
    c = SampleApp.mainloop() #error: parameter 'self' unfilled. ?
    bt = threading.Thread(target=b.run, args=())
    ct = threading.Thread(target=c.run, args=())
    bt.start()
    ct.start()

    #app = SampleApp()
    #before I used threading I called the sample app with:app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `c = SampleApp.mainloop()`: that's incorrect. You'd have to create an instance of your `SampleApp` first. Your question is unclear. Is there a syntax error, or can you point out where the code is locking up?

Comment: thanks, that's a start :). So i made Sampleapp an instance 'd'. and set c to 'c = d.mainloop().

Comment: the error i get is at the 'd= Sampleapp()'. but what is wierd isthat it refers to alot of different parts in the program and it says: _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage56"doesn't exist.